# I'm trying to solve the expression for Dirac exchange, but I'm not understanding the variables change employed. How can I perform it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, density-functional-theory, exchange-interaction

I'm trying to perform the variables change employed in the book "Density Functional Theory of Atoms and Molecules", by Parr and Weitao - page 108. But, from the expression of \rho_{1} given on page 107, this cannot seem to be possible.

[image: Variables change from first to second line]

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Ok Amit. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER. I am just parking some intermediate computation. I do not think you have quoted enough of the book to begin unpacking this question. In particular, even if I accept the result, I cannot get the conversion factor of $\dfrac{4\pi}{k_F^2}$ nor why it is power of 5 in the denominator rather than 7. I cannot help further than what I can see.</strike>
\begin{align}
\rho_1
&=\frac1{4\pi^3}\int_0^{k_F}k^2\,\mathrm dk
  \int_0^\pi\sin\vartheta\,e^{ikr_{12}\cos\vartheta}\,\mathrm d\vartheta
  \int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\varphi\\
&=\frac1{2\pi^2}\int_0^{k_F}k^2\,\mathrm dk
  \int_{-1}^{+1}e^{-ikr_{12}\chi}\,\mathrm d\chi\\
&=\frac1{2\pi^2}\int_0^{k_F}\frac{ik}{r_{12}}
  \left[e^{-ikr_{12}\chi}\right]_{\chi=-1}^{+1}\,\mathrm dk\\
&=\frac1{\pi^2r_{12}^3}\int_0^{k_Fr_{12}}\phi\sin\phi\,\mathrm d\phi\\
&=\frac1{\pi^2r_{12}^3}\left[-\phi\cos\phi+\sin\phi\right]_0^{k_Fr_{12}}\\
&=\frac{k_F^3}{\pi^2}\frac{\sin(k_Fr_{12})-k_Fr_{12}\cos(k_Fr_{12})}{(k_Fr_{12})^3}
\end{align}
Now, $k_F^3/3\pi^2=N/V=\rho$, and we can thus recover some equations in the text<strike>, but there are still confusing parts that are not solved.</strike>

---

The formula is
$$K_D[\rho]=\frac14\int\int\frac{[\rho_1]^2}s\,\mathrm d\vec r\,\mathrm d\vec s$$
and then with some variable changes you will get the factor of $k_F^2$ in the denominator and the power of 5 rather than power of 7. I will thus get the constant, the 4/3 power, everything.

It is important to note that the integral over $s$ is vectorial, but the denominator is just the scalar magnitude thereof. The angular integrals thus give us $4\pi s^2$, cancelling the denominator and bringing everything up, leading to the answer.

Comment: OK. Then, the error was in the book's notation. Great. Thank you for your help naturallyInconsistent.